# Way to pull out specific things from strings?

Tags: java

I have this really long list of over a thousand emails and names in the format of:

```
Name Class Email
Name Class Email
...Etc...
```

Is there a way that I could paste this whole list into a `JTextPane` or the Console and have a program pick out only the emails and print them?

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: Can you show us your efforts

Comment: Maybe you can use RegEx, but probably this will be a little overkill... [Look here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can start by tokenizing your incoming text with the delimiter. In your case I assume its a space character.

```
String str = "John C504 john@doe.com";
String[] arr = str.split(" ");

if(arr.length > 2){
    String email = arr[2];
}
```

Things to consider:

1. If the name has space characters in between eg: "John Doe" then this technique might not work. A better approach is to use a different delimiter in your text.
2. You can also use Regular Expressions to extract email address from the string. This technique wont be affected if say email address is present in the beginning/middle of the string instead of being at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but here's how I'd do it:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GiveEmails {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner infile = null;
        if (args.length == 1) {
            infile = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        }

        while (infile != null && infile.hasNext()) {
            String line = infile.nextLine();
            String[] linearray = line.split(" ");
            System.out.println(linearray[linearray.length-1]); // print the last token
        }       
    }
}
```

Takes a filename as the first argument, then returns the last token on each line, using space as a delimiter.